# What's the meaning of 'valid against' ? - 1963 US

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

[Source:](http://caselaw.lp.findlaw.com/scripts/getcase.pl?navby=CASE&court=US&vol=372&page=335) *Gideon v Wainwright* (1963)

> In agreeing with the Court that the right to counsel in a case
>   such as this should now be expressly recognized as a
>   fundamental right embraced in the Fourteenth Amendment,
>   I wish to make a further observation. When we hold a right
>   or immunity, **valid against** the Federal Government, to be
>   "implicit in the concept of ordered liberty" [Footnote 4/6] and
>   thus **valid against** the States, I do not read our past
>   decisions to suggest that, by so holding, we automatically
>   carry over an entire body of federal law and apply it in full
>   sweep to the States. Any such concept would disregard the
>   frequently wide disparity between the legitimate interests of
>   the States and of the Federal Government, the divergent
>   problems that they face, and the significantly different
>   consequences of their actions.

Comment: *Against* is like *vis-à-vis*.

Answer (score 2):

I assume "against" is associated with the validity of "immunity". Consider a similar use with "effective against":

> This medicine raises your immunity to certain disease. The medicine's immunity is effective against the measles and against smallpox.

Here, the judge is talking about a right that grants legal immunity against the power of certain governments. My example says that some medicine is *effective* when providing protection from certain diseases. The author here recognizes that some *legal right to immunity* is *legally valid* when providing protection from the Federal Government and the States' governments.

Also, because the first *valid against* is offset by commas, it appears to be a relative clause:

> When we hold a right or immunity ([**that is**] valid against the Federal Government) to be "implicit in the concept of ordered liberty" and thus valid against the States, ...